# How to get image/css-style, downloaded WebEngine

Tags: web, resources, javafx

I am using the following code for downloading and rendering web-page.

```
public class SwingFXWe extends Application {
public final WebEngine webEngine=null;

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {

    stage.setTitle("HTML");
    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());

    VBox root = new VBox();

    final WebView browser = new WebView();
    final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();


    String text = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String html="";
    try {
         FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\D.htm");
         InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, "windows-1251");
    reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
    while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        html+=text+"\n";
    }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

    webEngine.loadContent(Jsoup.parse(html).html());
    root.getChildren().addAll(browser);
    scene.setRoot(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch();
}
}
```

Can I get the images and styles from webEngine container, to change them?